# Drag and Drop in Windows Store Apps with touch

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps

I'd like to drag an user-defined object from a `ListView` onto another control.
Rights now it's working with the mouse, but not with touch.
how does it work with touch?

Edit: the objects are in an observable collection, which is binded to the `ListView`

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

So, the tough part about touch is that you have to "detach" the object by pulling it *orthogonal (perpendicular) to the scrolling axis*. What this means is, if it's a vertically scrolling list, you have to pull the item to the left or right to start dragging it. It should then act as intended.